# Is it Possible to Change Database connection within a stored Procedure- Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, database-connection

I was wondering if its possible to change database connections within a stored procedure. I want to query from my original database and then connect to a different DB, extract and insert data into my original DB connection? 
Not sure if this is possible. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: No. Not possible. You can use db link if you want to fetch data from other db.

Comment: Alternatively, you could extract the data from your "original database" to CSV and then upload into a different database using SQL Loader (`sqlldr.exe` on Windows).

Comment: You can't obviously *chnage db connection* while in PL/SQL procedure, but **you can set up a new connection** to a remote database using a Java procedure with the [server side  JDBC driver](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/ssid.htm#JJDBC28250) and extract so data. The usage of database links is of course more conviniante.

Comment: DB link is not an option since i have no access. Thanks for everyones input!